# Running libreoffice with intel graphics in a dual graphics amd environment

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, fglrx

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.02 on a Dell Inspiron 15-5547, AMD Radeon HD R7 M265 dual graphics with the fgrlx drivers. When switching to the intel graphics and running Libreoffice calc (I use 4.4.5 from the ppa), I get after a few seconds:

```
soffice
Error: No root privilege. Please check with the system-admin.
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly
```

Is there something that I could do to avoid this and be able to use Libreoffice with my intel graphics? (I would however prefer not uninstalling the driver). From my limited understanding when using the intel GPU I should not need the fglrx kernel module. Is this maybe a bug i could report and if yes, were? It does not seem to be an upstream problem.

Comment: Did you install fglrx or fglrx-updates?

Comment: Fglrx, fglrx-core. Updates is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this adapter you need to install another driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

You can see the supported adapters at [AMD site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86).

Comment: Thank you, I will check and vote. this however, might take a while as I cannot afford to put my laptop in an unusable state at the moment, and messing with proprietary drivers has led me there more than once.

Comment: I was very reluctant to try this, due to previous experience with proprietary drivers, but it did work. Could you add, a link to where someone can see which driver is for which adapter?

Comment: @Bruni Now it makes sense to install this driver for all supported AMD adapters. New cards are supported only by this one.